# web_custom_request in Loadrunner with GET method

Tags: rest, get, performance-testing, database-performance, loadrunner

I Have a REST service which is of GET Method whose request is passed through URL. Manually when I try in Rest CLient  i'm getting the valid response as shown below pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJkJS.png :-

**URL passed:-**

```
http://stg-services.star:9375/MobileCheckin/rest/KeylessMetrics?serviceRequest={"requestContextBean":{"requestTransactionID":"fa4dfc4b2b5244153e965361fcc8369711b59dad111020fdceafad16aa19","flowSeqNum":"567","globalContextParameters":["globalContext1","globalContext2"],"contextFrames":[{"name":"cfb1","type":"mci request","serviceInterface":"getResIdsByMetricName","operation":"getResIdsByMetricName","localContextParameters":[],"ipaddress":null},{"name":"cfb2","type":"mci request","serviceInterface":"getResIdsByMetricName","operation":"getResIdsByMetricName","localContextParameters":[],"ipaddress":null}]},"propId":421,"businessDate":"2016-06-30","metricName":["ALL"],"urgentlyWaitingTimeConfig":30}
```

**But same thing when i try in LR using web_custom_request, i receive Internal server error 500.**

```
    Action()
{
    web_custom_request("web_custom_request",
    "URL=http://stg-services.star:9375/MobileCheckin/rest/KeylessMetrics?serviceRequest={\"requestContextBean\":{\"requestTransactionID\":\"fa4dfc4b2b5244153e965361fcc8369711b59dad111020fdceafad16aa19\",\"flowSeqNum\":\"567\",\"globalContextParameters\":[\"globalContext1\",\"globalContext2\"],\"contextFrames\":[{\"name\":\"cfb1\",\"type\":\"mci request\",\"serviceInterface\":\"getResIdsByMetricName\",\"operation\":\"getResIdsByMetricName\",\"localContextParameters\":[],\"ipaddress\":null},{\"name\":\"cfb2\",\"type\":\"mci request\",\"serviceInterface\":\"getResIdsByMetricName\",\"operation\":\"getResIdsByMetricName\",\"localContextParameters\":[],\"ipaddress\":null}]},\"propId\":421,\"businessDate\":\"2016-06-30\",\"metricName\":[\"ALL\"],\"urgentlyWaitingTimeConfig\":30}",
    "Method=GET",
    "TargetFrame=",
    "RecContentType=application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Resource=0",
    "Referer=",
    "Mode=HTTP",
     LAST); 

    return 0;
}
```

**Response in LR:-**

```
Action.c(3):     HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error\r\n
Action.c(3):     X-Backside-Transport: FAIL FAIL,FAIL FAIL\r\n
Action.c(3):     Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
Action.c(3):     Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n
Action.c(3):     Content-Type: text/xml\r\n
Action.c(3):     Date: Thu, 30 Jun 2016 13:28:27 GMT\r\n
Action.c(3):     X-Client-IP: 10.132.132.6\r\n
Action.c(3):     X-Global-Transaction-ID: 12678193\r\n
Action.c(3):     \r\n
Action.c(3): t=411ms: 4-byte chunked response overhead for "http://stg-services.star:9375/MobileCheckin/rest/KeylessMetrics?serviceRequest={"requestContextBean":{"requestTransactionID":"fa4dfc4b2b5244153e965361fcc8369711b59dad111020fdceafad16aa19","flowSeqNum":"567","globalContextParameters":["globalContext1","globalContext2"],"contextFrames":[{"name":"cfb1","type":"mci request","serviceInterface":"getResIdsByMetricName","operation":"getResIdsByMetricName","localContextParameters":[],"ipaddress":null},{"name":"cfb2","type":"mci request","serviceInterface":"getResIdsByMetricName","operation":"getResIdsByMetricName","localContextParameters":[],"ipaddress":null}]},"propId":421,"businessDate":"2016-06-30","metricName":["ALL"],"urgentlyWaitingTimeConfig":30}" (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=1)
Action.c(3):     fe\r\n
Action.c(3): t=411ms: 7-byte chunked response overhead for "http://stg-services.star:9375/MobileCheckin/rest/KeylessMetrics?serviceRequest={"requestContextBean":{"requestTransactionID":"fa4dfc4b2b5244153e965361fcc8369711b59dad111020fdceafad16aa19","flowSeqNum":"567","globalContextParameters":["globalContext1","globalContext2"],"contextFrames":[{"name":"cfb1","type":"mci request","serviceInterface":"getResIdsByMetricName","operation":"getResIdsByMetricName","localContextParameters":[],"ipaddress":null},{"name":"cfb2","type":"mci request","serviceInterface":"getResIdsByMetricName","operation":"getResIdsByMetricName","localContextParameters":[],"ipaddress":null}]},"propId":421,"businessDate":"2016-06-30","metricName":["ALL"],"urgentlyWaitingTimeConfig":30}" (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=1)
Action.c(3):     \r\n
Action.c(3):     0\r\n
Action.c(3):     \r\n
Action.c(3): t=416ms: 254-byte chunked response body for "http://stg-services.star:9375/MobileCheckin/rest/KeylessMetrics?serviceRequest={"requestContextBean":{"requestTransactionID":"fa4dfc4b2b5244153e965361fcc8369711b59dad111020fdceafad16aa19","flowSeqNum":"567","globalContextParameters":["globalContext1","globalContext2"],"contextFrames":[{"name":"cfb1","type":"mci request","serviceInterface":"getResIdsByMetricName","operation":"getResIdsByMetricName","localContextParameters":[],"ipaddress":null},{"name":"cfb2","type":"mci request","serviceInterface":"getResIdsByMetricName","operation":"getResIdsByMetricName","localContextParameters":[],"ipaddress":null}]},"propId":421,"businessDate":"2016-06-30","metricName":["ALL"],"urgentlyWaitingTimeConfig":30}" (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=1)
Action.c(3):     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n
Action.c(3):     <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Body><env:Fault><
Action.c(3):     faultcode>env:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Internal Error (from server)</faultstring></e
Action.c(3):     nv:Fault></env:Body></env:Envelope>
Action.c(3): Error -26612: HTTP Status-Code=500 (Internal Server Error) for "http://stg-services.star:9375/MobileCheckin/rest/KeylessMetrics?serviceRequest={"requestContextBean":{"requestTransactionID":"fa4dfc4b2b5244153e965361fcc8369711b59dad111020fdceafad16aa19","flowSeqNum":"567","globalContextParameters":["globalContext1","globalContext2"],"contextFrames":[{"name":"cfb1","type":"mci request","serviceInterface":"getResIdsByMetricName","operation":"getResIdsByMetricName","localContextParameters":[],"ipaddress":null},{"name":"cfb2","type":"mci request","serviceInterface":"getResIdsByMetricName","operation":"getResIdsByMetricName","localContextParameters":[],"ipaddress":null}]},"propId":421,"businessDate":"2016-06-30","metricName":["ALL"],"urgentlyWaitingTimeConfig":30}"   [MsgId: MERR-26612] Action.c(3): t=433ms: Closing connection [0] to stg-services.star after receiving status code 500   [MsgId: MMSG-26000] Action.c(3): t=433ms: Closed connection [0] to stg-services.star:9375 after completing 0 requests   [MsgId: MMSG-26000]
Action.c(3): t=433ms: Request done "http://stg-services.star:9375/MobileCheckin/rest/KeylessMetrics?serviceRequest={"requestContextBean":{"requestTransactionID":"fa4dfc4b2b5244153e965361fcc8369711b59dad111020fdceafad16aa19","flowSeqNum":"567","globalContextParameters":["globalContext1","globalContext2"],"contextFrames":[{"name":"cfb1","type":"mci request","serviceInterface":"getResIdsByMetricName","operation":"getResIdsByMetricName","localContextParameters":[],"ipaddress":null},{"name":"cfb2","type":"mci request","serviceInterface":"getResIdsByMetricName","operation":"getResIdsByMetricName","localContextParameters":[],"ipaddress":null}]},"propId":421,"businessDate":"2016-06-30","metricName":["ALL"],"urgentlyWaitingTimeConfig":30}"    [MsgId: MMSG-26000]
Action.c(3): web_custom_request("web_custom_request") highest severity level was "ERROR", 254 body bytes, 256 header bytes, 11 chunking overhead bytes      [MsgId: MMSG-26387]
Ending action Action.
Ending iteration 1.
Ending Vuser...
Starting action vuser_end.
Ending action vuser_end.
Vuser Terminated.
```

Only change from Restclient and LR is in format of URL I'm passing. Could some one please help on why I'm recieving the internal server error in LR where as getting valid response in RESTclient.

Comment: Looks like some headers are missing in the request generated by LR. You could install Fiddler tool, record both RestClient and VuGen requests with it, then compare their headers.

Comment: Thanks Tserg. The problem was with the format of URL which was getting passed . The url format obtained from fiddler solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest recording this conversation twice from your restClient through the proxy recorder of LoadRunner.   I suspect from looking at some of the fields and values that you may have unhandled dynamic data involved.   In specific, these items pop out at items that likely need to be addressed:

- requestTransactionID
- flowSeqNum
- businessDate

I could see the top two elements being dynamic and the last one requiring a parameter to move beyond today's date

Check the values when recording multiple times.

You could also be missing a header.  WHen you record be sure to record all headers to capture what may be missing.

Comment: Thanks James for the response.when I hit the url with the same item data parameters in the rest client I get the valid response multiple times. If the item data u mentioned was dynamic then the response in rest client should also error out when tried with same parameters more than once. Also there are no headers used.

Comment: I am guessing you did not record it twice and compare the items noted.